# R: unzipping large compressed .csv yields "zip file is corrupt" warning

Tags: r, csv, unzip

I am downloading a 78MB zip file from the UN FAO, which contains a 2.66GB csv. I am able to unzip the the downloaded file from a folder using winzip, but have been unable to unzip the file using `unzip()` in R:

**Warning - 78MB download!**

```
url <- "http://fenixservices.fao.org/faostat/static/bulkdownloads/FoodBalanceSheets_E_All_Data_(Normalized).zip"
path <- file.path(getwd(),"/zipped_data.zip")
download.file(url, path, mode = "wb")
unzipped_data <- unzip(path)
```

This results in a warning and a failure to unzip the file:

> Warning message
>
> In unzip(path) : zip file is corrupt

In the `?unzip` documentation I see

> "It does have some support for bzip2 compression and > 2GB zip files (but not >= 4GB files pre-compression contained in a zip file: like many builds of unzip it may truncate these, in R's case with a warning if possible)"

This makes me believe that `unzip()` should handle my file, but this same process has successfully downloaded, unzipped, and read multiple other smaller tables from the FAOstat. Is there a chance that the size of my csv is the source of this error? If so, what is the workaround?

Comment: you could build a shell command in R calling winzip on your file and execute it with the `shell` function from R. if you wrap it into a function `unzip2` there won't be much difference

Comment: I've seen this idea on other posts suggesting `system` but I haven't seen an example. Could you provide one, or point me in the right direction? Thanks for the help!

Comment: See my answer, please give me some feedback so I can improve it as it's untested and contains some uncertainties.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem running `unzip()` on Ubuntu Server 20.04. Setting argument `unzip(..., unzip = "/usr/bin/unzip")`, instead of `unzip = "internal"`, did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test my solution and it also depends on your installation but hopefully that'll work or at least point you to a suitable solution:

You can run winzip through command line, [this page shows the structure of the call](http://www.memecode.com/docs/winzip.html)

And you can also run command lines from R, with `system` or `shell` (which is just a wrapper for `system`

The command line general structure to extract would be:

```
winzip32 -e [options] filename[.zip] folder
```

So we create a string with this structure and your input paths, and we create a function around it that mimics `unzip` with parameters `zipfile` and `exdir`

```
unzip_wz <- function(zipfile,exdir){
  dir.create(exdir,recursive = FALSE,showWarnings=FALSE) # I don't know how/if unzip creates folders, you might want to tweak or remove this line altogether
  str1 <- sprintf("winzip32 -e '%s' '%s'",zipfile,exdir)
  shell(str1,wait = TRUE)  # set to FALSE if you want the program to keep running while unzipping, proceed with caution but in some cases that could be an improvement of your current solution
}
```

You can try to use this function in place of `unzip`. It assumes that winzip32 was added to your system path variables, if it isn't, either add it, or replace it by the exec full name so you have something like:

```
str1 <- sprintf("'C://probably/somewhere/in/program/files/winzip32.exe' -e '%s' '%s'",zipfile,exdir)
```

PS: use full paths! the command line doesn't know your working directories (we could implement the feature in our function if needed).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards winzip cmd syntax. I haven't been successful even unzipping my file from command line yet though. Ultimately, using a system command may not be a solution for me - I'm trying to write a script that rebuilds tables that are hosted on a network drive. It needs to run from any users machine with an R installation, so pointing to a local installation of winzip might be problematic, though likely the path is the same on most of our organization's machines.

Comment: Maybe it was a bit too obvious, but this may do the trick! https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zip/index.html

Comment: Or this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.97/topics/UnZip

Comment: Giving zip a try (linux) immediately after `warning: zip file is corrupt`, shows this `* DONE (zip)

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpDgwPmW/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (./:617d4dbbd.flac)`, connection listing is first desired file, of large zip, so perhaps corruption has to do with not cleaning up...This in the case where `files = some_character_vec_of_the_files_desired` is used.  installing zip really solved this not too obvious problem.